# How do I get x,y, values of qml element after moving with mouse area?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

Using Qt5 official release --

I need to save the x,y properties of an image element. This

```
QObject* pic = rootitem1->findChild<QObject*>("image_objectName");
int x = pic->property("x").toInt();
```

gives the value the property was originally set with, but what I need is the current value after the image has been moved by the mouse. I'm probably missing something simple but I can't find any thing else on it. Really would appreciate any help, THANKS.

Comment: Figured it out. For any one else looking use mapToScene().